# JSX tag has a child, but VSCode says that property `children` is missing in props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsx

I have a very simple TypeScript/React/TSX setup but the following piece of code shows an error:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

export default function Index() {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div>Hello world</div>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

The `<Layout [...]>` tag is underlined in red, saying: `Property 'children' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'LayoutProps'.ts(2741)`.

Indeed, the props (`LayoutProps`) of the `Layout` component requires children:

```js
export interface LayoutProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}
```

However, as you see in the first snippet, there is actually a child, a `<div/>`. I'm trying to figure out why it is not "detected" by TypeScript.

If I define the `children` prop as an JSX attribute, as in `<Layout children={null} />`, the error disappears, as if I could only define children using this syntax.

I'm using TypeScript v3.7.4 with [a basic React/NextJS-friendly tsconfig.json](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs-with-typescript/tsconfig.json).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [npm-update-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-update-all) to ensure everything was up to date, and it fixed my problem. The project was new, so I previously assumed that npm would have installed "fresh" dependencies, but it wasn't the case by the look of things.

Answer (score 0):

How are you typing your Layout component props? This should work without typescript errors.

Layout.tsx

```
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const Layout = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};
```

Index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Layout } from "./Layout";

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>Hello world</div>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Comment: Everything was fine regarding the `Layout` implementation, I have React-ready snippets that I've been using for a long time. I fixed my problem by force-updating my dependencies. Thanks anyways for taking the time to answer, I appreciate it.